# Assign a SAS macro variable with quotes to a data step var

Tags: sas

How to make below statement works?

```
%let qccomment= /n ORACLE execute error: ORA-20001: User xyxlll
        does not have acccess to the gva BA_DEV ORA-06512: at 
        "M_UTIL", line 51 ORA-06512: at line 1. /nTable XY_XY does not exist 
        (Oracle extract data failed);   

%put &qccomment;
data null;
    i ="&qccomment";
    put i;
run;
```

It return with error 
ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SYMGET() function to retrieve the value a macro variable without having to worry about any macro quoting (at least in the step that is doing the retrieval).

```
data _null_;
   i = symget('qcomment');
   put i= ;
run;
```

If you really did need to reference the macro variable's value and use it to generate a quoted string then use the QUOTE() function to insure that any embedded quotes are properly doubled so that the generated string is a valid string literal.

```
data _null_;
   put %sysfunc(quote(&qcomment));
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use macro quoting function to get around this,

```
/* Using %BQUOTE in let statement to quote the string */
%let qccomment= %bquote(/n ORACLE execute error: ORA-20001: User xyxlll
    does not have acccess to the gva BA_DEV ORA-06512: at 
    "M_UTIL", line 51 ORA-06512: at line 1. /nTable XY_XY does not exist 
    (Oracle extract data failed));

%put &qccomment;
data null;
    i ="&qccomment";
    put i;
run;
```

**LOG**

```
11   %let qccomment= %bquote(/n ORACLE execute error: ORA-20001: User xyxlll
12           does not have acccess to the gva BA_DEV ORA-06512: at
13           "M_UTIL", line 51 ORA-06512: at line 1. /nTable XY_XY does not     exist
14           (Oracle extract data failed));
15
16   %put &qccomment;
/n ORACLE execute error: ORA-20001: User xyxlll         does not have     acccess to the gva BA_DEV
ORA-06512: at         "M_UTIL", line 51 ORA-06512: at line 1. /nTable XY_XY     does not exist
   (Oracle extract data failed)
17   data null;
18       i ="&qccomment";
19       put i;
20   run;

/n ORACLE execute error: ORA-20001: User xyxlll         does not have acccess to the gva BA_DEV
ORA-06512: at         "M_UTIL", line 51 ORA-06512: at line 1. /nTable XY_XY does not exist
   (Oracle extract data failed)
NOTE: The data set WORK.NULL has 1 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.08 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you, Vishant. It can work but in my real case, the macro variable is auto generated but not assigned directly. The previous Tom's solution can help me on it. :)

Comment: @Greatvia- It would be great if you can mention the same thing as your requirement in your question, as in your question you are requesting for a solution to your error. Please keep this in mind going forward.